# Use substring and Concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I have the following date 20180305 in my database stored as a varchar(8).

I'd like to switch the format of the date to DDMMYYYY

I can see the elements split with using a substring - like below-

```
Substring ([Transaction Date],7,2) [Accounting Period] ,
        Substring ([Transaction Date],5,2) [Accounting Period],
        Substring ([Transaction Date],1,4) [Accounting Period]
```

But how do I combine them with a CONCAT?

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to change something, it should be the datatype. **Never** store dates in a varchar column, **always** use the appropriate datatype.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: You really should listen to what @HoneyBadger is saying. Storing dates as strings is just a horrible idea. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!  Change the data structure:

```
alter table t alter column [Transaction Date] date;
```

You are fortunate.  Your format will convert correctly.

Then, if you want it in a particular format, use a computed column:

```
alter table t add column transaction_date_mmddyyyy as
    (replace(convert(varchar(10), [Transaction Date], 105), '-', '') )
```

Then you can use the date -- as a date, the right way to store it.  You can also fetch the presentation format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are working with SQL Server, if so then you can use :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('20180305' AS date), 105), '-','') AS [Accounting Period]
FROM table t;
```